# Converge API : error 4007 - CVV2 Requested But No Data

Tags: payment-gateway, payment

Request Url:

https://api.demo.convergepay.com/VirtualMerchantDemo/processxml.do

Here is my Sample Xml Request:

```
<txn>
  <ssl_merchant_id>MERCHANTID12345</ssl_merchant_id>
  <ssl_user_id>USERID12345</ssl_user_id>
  <ssl_pin>PIN1245</ssl_pin>
  <ssl_test_mode>false</ssl_test_mode>
  <ssl_transaction_type>ccsale</ssl_transaction_type>
  <ssl_card_number>5472063333333330</ssl_card_number>
  <ssl_exp_date>0118</ssl_exp_date>
  <ssl_amount>1.00</ssl_amount>
</txn>
```

My Result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<txn>
  <errorCode>4007</errorCode>
  <errorName>CVV2 Requested But No Data</errorName>
  <errorMessage>CVV2 check cannot be performed as no data was supplied in the authorization request.</errorMessage>
</txn>
```

However, simply changing my own credentials with the public pin on the dev website at: https://developer.elavon.com/#/api/eb6e9106-0172-4305-bc5a-b3ebe832f823.rcosoomi/versions/5180a9f2-741b-439c-bced-5c84a822f39b.rcosoomi/documents/?converge-integration-guide/book/transaction_types/credit_card/sale.html

I get the correct response.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<txn>
  <ssl_card_short_description>MC</ssl_card_short_description>
  <ssl_cvv2_response></ssl_cvv2_response>
  <ssl_account_balance>1.00</ssl_account_balance>
  <ssl_result_message>APPROVAL</ssl_result_message>
  <ssl_invoice_number></ssl_invoice_number>
  <ssl_promo_code></ssl_promo_code>
  <ssl_result>0</ssl_result>
  <ssl_txn_id>200118A15-9C4ECA77-4A72-425F-9F8A-4F9E27B93DB2</ssl_txn_id>
  <ssl_completion_date></ssl_completion_date>
  <ssl_transaction_type>SALE</ssl_transaction_type>
  <ssl_avs_response> </ssl_avs_response>
  <ssl_account_status></ssl_account_status>
  <ssl_approval_code>CMC675</ssl_approval_code>
  <ssl_enrollment></ssl_enrollment>
  <ssl_exp_date>1225</ssl_exp_date>
  <ssl_loyalty_program></ssl_loyalty_program>
  <ssl_tender_amount></ssl_tender_amount>
  <ssl_departure_date></ssl_departure_date>
  <ssl_card_type>CREDITCARD</ssl_card_type>
  <ssl_loyalty_account_balance></ssl_loyalty_account_balance>
  <ssl_salestax></ssl_salestax>
  <ssl_amount>1.00</ssl_amount>
  <ssl_card_number>54**********3330</ssl_card_number>
  <ssl_issue_points></ssl_issue_points>
  <ssl_txn_time>01/20/2018 09:13:19 AM</ssl_txn_time>
  <ssl_access_code></ssl_access_code>
</txn>
```

Thus, my demo org must be set up to require a cvv2 code. How do I fix this?
 Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Can be fixed by logging into the web portal, then navigating to

terminal (click on) -> payment fields -> then setting the cvv2 field as not required.

Comment: For me, it's impossible to make the cvv2 field not required because it's disabled in the form...

Comment: You will probably have to call them for support in this case.